# mapStateToProps() in Connect() must return a plain object. Instead received undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a problem with displaying data.

In my application I use react and redux.

In the console I will get an error `mapStateToProps() in Connect(ListPets) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.`

This is my main component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import loadData from '../actions/actions';

class ListPets extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { loadData } = this.props;
    loadData();
    console.log(loadData );
  }

  render() {
    const { dataPet } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadData: () => dispatch(loadData())
  }
};
```

This fragment `console.log(loadData );` display

```
ƒ loadData() {
      return dispatch(Object(_actions_actions__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["default"])());
    }
```

When I add the code `{dataPet.data}` in div. I get  an error]. As if this data was not in the store, I do not know...

this my reducer function

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  dataPet: [],
};

const fetchDataReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.types) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      }
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        dataPet: action.dataPet,
      }
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
      }
  };
}
```

Data is well downloaded, because the console receives the `FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS` action.

I have no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: @HemadriDasari this is my code  codesandbox.io/embed/rj4yz06xqm?fontsize=14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes on your code, try this now...should work
https://codesandbox.io/s/z2volo1n6m

Comment: in reducer you're using action.types, you need to use action.type....i change my codesandbox

Answer (score 2):

In your reducer you have a typo:

```
const fetchDataReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.types) { // here
```

It should be `action.type` not `action.types`.

Answer (score 0):

If `thing` is an object in state:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  thing: state.thing,
});
```

Then use like:

`this.props.thing` in your component

Comment: I update ---- const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  dataPet: state.dataPet,
}); ---- but I get this error ----TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataPet' of undefined ----

Comment: Do you have the Redux devtools installed? Can you verify the state is in the structure you expect?

Comment: i have redux-logger. when I have this --- const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state
}); ---- I get  action FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS @ 12:21:07.618

Comment: You might want to set up a CodeSandbox demo... my feeling here is the state is not updated.